# Bash during k8s init container cannot understand bash

Tags: bash, kubernetes

Hi looking for some help in explaining what this line is doing. I am completely lost in what it is saying. I know it is exiting there because I can see my log line 25 but NOT log line 27.

```bash
[[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
```

```yaml
      initContainers:
      - name: init-mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          # Generate mysql server-id from pod ordinal index.
          echo "Running line25" >> /var/lib/mysql/temp.log
          [[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
          echo "Running line27" >> /var/lib/mysql/temp.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs the `hostname` command, and then compares its output to the regular expression `-([0-9]+)$`. The parentheses are redundant, so it could be simplified to `-[0-9]+$`; this is "a string that ends with `-` and 1 or more digits".

If the output of `hostname` doesn't match the expression, `exit 1` is called. You can look at the output of `hostname` separately to see its value.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I have to say that the issue had nothing to do with the statement. I assumed that "hostname" function was available but in fact, in the image, it was not. So I had to add the line "yum -y install hostname" to the file "mysql-statefulset.yaml" at initContainers.init-mysql bash cmd. This is from the K8s Tutorial "https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/"

Comment: Ah, okay. When you run a non-existing command, shells usually print to stderr, but command substitution by default captures stdout, so the conditional would compare the empty string to your regex, and doesn't match.